# Print next array after matching array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays that contain array key with the value, here the example :

```
$text = [
        [
         'Hotel'     => 'N',
         'Jayakarta' => 'NE',
         'Jaya'      => 'NE',
         'sangat'    => 'ADV',
         'nyaman'    => 'ADJ',
         'ditempati' => 'V.'
        ]
        ,
        [
         'Andi'     => 'NOB',
         'menginap' => 'V',
         'di'       => 'PREP',
         'Hotel'    => 'N',
         'Neo'      => 'NE',
         'Malioboro => 'NE',
         'selama'   => 'N',
         'satu'     => 'NUM',
         'minggu'   => 'N.'
        ]
    ];
```

And I have array prefix that contain :

```
$prefix = [ [0] => Hotel [1] => Hostel [2] => Losmen [3] => Motel [4] => Penginapan [5] => Pesanggrahan [6] => Pondok [7] => Wisma ]
```

If $prefix elements are in $text array then I will check next array value of text. If array value is N or NE then I will make an output from prefix text until the end of array that contain value N or NE.

Here's what I am doing for the moment:

```
foreach($text as $index => $tok){
    foreach ($tok as $tokkey => $tokvalue) {
        if(in_array($tokkey, $prefix)){
            echo $tokkey;
            $next = next($tok);
            if($tokvalue == "N" or $tokvalue == "NE"){
                echo key($tok);
            }     
        }
   }
}
```

The output I got :

```
Hotel Jayakarta, Hotel menginap
```

The expected output should be:

```
- Hotel Jayakarta Jaya
- Hotel Neo Malioboro selama
```

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get? You're code works in my computer!

Comment: @Fredster output added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps I followed to get the desired out put.

1) If tokkey present in prefix array, call a function.

2) Create a new array starting from the element which matches with prefix array.

3) Loop the new array and check for next value to be either 'N' or 'NE'

4) Display those keys from array.

```
foreach($text as $index => $tok){
    foreach ($tok as $tokkey => $tokvalue) {
        if(in_array($tokkey, $prefix)){
            getKeys($tokkey,$tok);
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
}

function getKeys($tokkey,$tok){
    $flag = 0;
    echo $tokkey.' ';
    foreach($tok as $k=>$v){
        if($k==$tokkey){
            $flag = 1;
        }
        if($flag){
            $new_array[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
    foreach($new_array as $k=>$v){
        $ff = next($new_array);
        if(($ff == 'NE' || $ff == 'N')){
             echo key($new_array).' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Out Put:

Hotel Jayakarta Jaya 
Hotel Neo Malioboro selama

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2777d3ab3d34c941c23886d42e537cde7fff2351

Comment: When I tried your code, the output I got is different with yours. My output is like missing the second token, for example : Hotel Jaya, Hotel Malioboro selama. But I already fix it. thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your text, you need to replace your `if()` that only runs once, for a `while()` that runs while the `next()` string is NE or N.

```
foreach($text as $index => $tok){
    foreach ($tok as $tokkey => $tokvalue) {
        if(in_array($tokkey, $prefix)){
            echo $tokkey;
            next($tok);
            while($tokvalue == "N" || $tokvalue == "NE")
            {    echo key($tok); 
                 next($tok); 
                 $tokvalue = current($tok);
            }
            }
        }
        echo "\n";      
   }
}
```